# Traverse to all parent table of a given tables

Tags: java, sql, oracle, java-8, jdbc-odbc

I am currently doing standalone application, to traverse to all its parent table and traverse till child table has no parent.
example

```
 Table1 
   |_ Table 2
      |_ Table 2.1
      |_ Table 2.2
      |_ Table 2.3
         |_ Table 2.3.a
         |_ Table 2.3.b
  |_ Table 3
      |_ Table 3.1
      |_ Table 3.2
      |_ Table 3.3
         |_ Table 3.3.a
         |_ Table 3.3.b
   |_ Table 4
```

In this example, I need to reach all the parent tables no matter how big the relation is, Can anyone help me to solve this

After reaching to Table 2.3.b again it sgould come to Table 3 which is 2nd parent of table 1

Currently, I can fetch  Table 2.1,Table 2.2,Table 2.3,by beow code

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SqlCheck {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

            Connection connection = null;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ganesh", "789", "987");
            PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk FROM all_cons_columns a JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R' AND a.table_name = ?");
            st.setString(1, "ITEM");
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();

            List parentTables=new ArrayList();

            while(rs.next()){
                //Retrieve by column name
                String id  = rs.getString("table_name");
                String age = rs.getString("column_name");
                String first = rs.getString("constraint_name");
                String parentTable = rs.getString("r_table_name");
                String first3 = rs.getString("r_pk");

                System.out.println(Got parent Tables +"   PPPPPPPPP");
                parentTables.add(parentTable);

            }

            Iterator listOfParentTable=parentTables.iterator();
            while (listOfParentTable.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println("=============11========");
                String string = (String) listOfParentTable.next();
                String s1=  "SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk FROM all_cons_columns a JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R' "
                        + "AND a.table_name = ?";

                PreparedStatement st2 = connection.prepareStatement(s1);
                st2.setString(1, string);
                ResultSet rs1=st2.executeQuery();

                while(rs1.next()){
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    String id  = rs1.getString("table_name");
                    String age = rs1.getString("column_name");
                    String first = rs1.getString("constraint_name");
                    String parentTable1 = rs1.getString("r_table_name");
                    String first3 = rs1.getString("r_pk");

                    System.out.println(string+"   "+parentTable1);

                }
            }
            System.out.println("WELDONE     ^^^^^^^^");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check System.output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion is appriciated

Comment: what are you doing is get all root tables & expand all tables on root tables recursively? if it is, you need push tables need to expand in a `stack` or using recursive call for traversing.

Comment: used recursion, able to  fix the issue